# Firefox: Focus an element inside a link using the tab key

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility

I have a button inside an a tag, that should be focusable via the tab key.

```
<a href="#">
    <button tabindex="0">Do something</button>
</a>
```

Using the Firefox property **accessibility.tabfocus = 7**, I can only focus the wrapping link, but not the child button. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: I think you should make up your mind: use a button (to *do* something) or use a link (to *navigate* somewhere). You should not combine the two because how is a screenreader supposed to announce this UI element? As a button or as a link?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I turned the link into a button now, using the role="button" attribute. Now you can see the focus outline. Strangely, using this configuration(accessibility.tabfocus = 7), I noticed that FF is not showing a focus for buttons in general.

Comment: But why do you misuse a link as a button? Is there any reason not to have a real button `<button type="button">..</button>`?

Comment: The link is used to scroll to a jumpmark('#section-example'), once it is clicked.

Comment: I really don't understand why you add `role=button` to a link that is used to navigate somewhere. This causes the link to be announced as a button, which misleads screenreader users about the UI component they are dealing with. And focus visibility should be defined with CSS, not by abusing ARIA roles.

Comment: In case you’re not aware: this is invalid HTML. An interactive element may not contain an interactive element.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you could get this to work, it is **not** valid HTML so could easily break on any browser or, if it happens to work now, it could break in the future.

[`<a>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) spec says:

> **Content model:**
>       Transparent, but there must be ***no interactive content*** or <a> element descendants.

Because the code is not valid HTML, it would fail [WCAG 4.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#parsing).

> **Success Criterion 4.1.1 Parsing:** In content implemented using markup languages, elements have complete start and end tags, **elements are nested according to their specifications**, elements do not contain duplicate attributes, and any IDs are unique, except where the specifications allow these features.